# Using commas in dollar values in a printed table

Tags: python, formatting

I'm printing a table - several rows containing various variable types - 
example:

```
print('{:10s} ${:12.0f}  {:10.1f}%'.format(ID,value,change))

first      $324681         2.4%
```

where the integers 10, 12, and 10 provide the column spacing I want.

But I want to have the $ amounts printed with a comma separator, thus:

```
print('{:10s} ${:,.0f}  {:10.1f}%'.format(ID,value,change))

first      $324,681         2.4%
```

But this loses the '12' spaces allowed for the second item.

But when I try

```
print('{:10s} ${:,12.0f}  {:10.1f}%'.format(ID,value,change))
```

I get `"ValueError: Invalid format specifier"`

How can I get both the commas and control over the column spacing?

Python 3.6 running in Spyder.

Answer (score 0):

If you are content to have the specified total width but the dollar in a fixed column possibly separated from the digits, then you could just do what you were doing, but with the `12` before the `,`.

```
>>> value = 324681
>>> ID = "first"
>>> change = 2.4
>>> print('{:10s} ${:12,.0f}  {:10.1f}%'.format(ID,value,change))
first      $     324,681         2.4%
```

If you want the numbers to follow immediately after the `$`, then you can format it as a string without any padding, and then use the string in a fixed-width format specifier:

```
>>> print('{:10s} {:13s}  {:10.1f}%'.format(ID ,'${:,.0f}'.format(value), change))
first       $324,681             2.4%
```

or:

```
>>> print('{:10s} {:>13s}  {:10.1f}%'.format(ID ,'${:,.0f}'.format(value), change))
first           $324,681         2.4%
```

(The width specifier is increased to 13 here, because the `$` sign itself is in addition to the 12 characters used for the number.)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
print('{:10s} ${:1,d} {:10.1f}%'.format('first', 324681, 2.4))
```

OUTPUT:

```
first      $324,681        2.4%
```